# Where can I find the viewer node for the shader editor?

Tags: node-editor

I am searching for this "viewer" node in shader editor...
[image: this guy is using viewer node on shader mode]

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + Left Click

Answer (score 3):

The viewer node is a simple emission node, it is just created by the node wrangler addon. Once the node wrangler addon is enabled, the addon creates such a node when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on the node.

Comment: Is Ctrl+Shift+click the only way to invoke it? I tried to find it using F3 or in the menus, but there was no such thing. I am not good at memorising all the complicated shortcuts so I would prefer finding it in the GUI.